# What is the functional derivative of the inverse function?

Tags: functional-analysis

A simple question. What the answer to $ \frac{\delta f^{-1}(x)}{\delta f(y) }$ ?

The more general question is, what is

$ \frac{\delta f^N(x)}{\delta f(y) }$ where this is the Nth iterate. $f^N(x) = f(f(f...f(x)...))$ ? The inverse function being the case where N=-1.

Not this is the **functional derivative** not the derivative.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{\delta f^{-1}(x)}{\delta f(y)} = \frac{\delta f^{-1}(f(y))}{\delta f(y)} = (f^{-1})'(f(y))=(f^{-1})'(x) $?

Comment: You're thinking of the normal derivative. I'm talking about the functional derivative.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $y=f(x)$ you have from $x=f(f^{-1}(x))$:
$$ 0 =\delta(x)=  \delta\; f (f^{-1}(x))= \delta f (y) \ + \  f'(y)  \ \ \delta f^{-1} (x)$$ from which you get:
$$\frac{\delta f^{-1} (x)}{\delta f (y)} = -\frac{1}{f'(y)} . $$
 For general $N$ I think that the question need not make sense as you need to evaluate at different points along the orbit (unless you look at a fixed point of $f$).

Comment: I can't read it off from there. My guess is $-\frac{\delta(f^{-1}(x)-y) }{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$. Is that what you got?

Comment: You're answer can't be correct since the right hand side depends only on y!

Comment: So you mean that I shouldn't make the assumption of $y=f(x)$? Then your guess may be correct, but it is not completely obvious how you would define it rigorously. Perhaps you should state something about the context in which you want to make this funcitonal derivative?